# How to pass more one code block to a function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I don't know any Ruby and am reading some documentationon it now.
A doubt I have just after reading about using code blocks and the "yield" keyword is whether it is possible to pass more than one code block to a function, and use both at will from within the called function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass only one block at once but blocks are actually `Proc` instances and you can pass as many instances you wish as parameters.

```
def mymethod(proc1, proc2, &block)
  proc1.call
  yield if block_given?
  proc2.call
end

mymethod(Proc.new {}, Proc.new {}) do
  # ...
end
```

However, it rarely makes sense.

Comment: Blocks aren't exactly procs.  They have common usecases and syntaxes, but they have enough implementation differences to cause confusing behavior.  It's a bit pedantic, but the scoping difference has bit me before.

Comment: @fengb I just made a test. http://gist.github.com/242746 Do you have some more documentation about the difference between Proc and block? Ruby is telling me a block is a Proc.

Comment: Blocks are implicitly "typecasted" to proc by using the &var syntax.  But there are certain operations that behave differently when used as a block versus a proc.

Long winded but comprehensive comparison:
http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb

Comment: Thanks. This is a long article, I'm going to crunch it in small pieces. :)

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, using the `yield` statement only supports one code block that's passed to the function.

Of course, you can pass a function multiple other functions or "code block objects" (`Proc` objects), and use them, but not by simply using `yield`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Proc` objects and pass around as many as you like.

I recommend reading [this page](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb) to understand the subtleties of all different block- and closure-like constructs Ruby has.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `call` method rather than yield to handle two separate blocks passed in.

Here's how:

```
def mood(state, happy, sad )
  if (state== :happy)
    happy.call
  else
    sad.call
  end
end

mood(:happy, Proc.new {puts 'yay!'} , Proc.new {puts 'boo!'})
mood(:sad, Proc.new {puts 'yay!'} , Proc.new {puts 'boo!'})
```

You can pass args with for example:

```
happy.call('very much')
```

arguments work just like you'd expect in blocks:

```
Proc.new {|amount| puts "yay #{amount} !"}
```